# I have this error when I start a Symfony project

Tags: php

```
$ composer require server --dev
Restricting packages listed in "symfony/symfony" to "4.4.*"
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Restricting packages listed in "symfony/symfony" to "4.4.*"
Nothing to install or update
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
ocramius/package-versions: Generating version class...
ocramius/package-versions: ...done generating version class
Executing script cache:clear [KO]
 [KO]
Script cache:clear returned with error code 1
!!
!!  In Kernel.php line 547:
!!
!!    Notice: fwrite(): write of 785 bytes failed with errno=13 Permission denied
!!
!!
!!
Script @auto-scripts was called via post-update-cmd

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Answer (score -1):

```
!!    Notice: fwrite(): write of 785 bytes failed with errno=13 Permission denied
```

The message is clear, your current user does not have sufficient permissions to write in composer dir.
Maybe `composer install` have had been run as root ?

Comment: i did composer install befor !

Comment: Yes, that's not what I am saying. Somehow something is wrong with your permissions. Something probably belong to root and your current user can not delete/overwrite it

Comment: Can you try to lauch your composer require with sudo ?

Comment: it was about php version, now i put the last version of php and it works ! thank you everybody